# Doctrine missing "WHERE" clause

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, docker, doctrine

I'm attempting to move my Behat tests from Jenkins (which builds a server each run), to Docker, so that I can add it to Travis.

I've run in to a little problem where the `WHERE` part of a query isn't being inserted by Doctrine. The DQL output is this:

```
SELECT v FROM \Database\Entity\SoftwareVersion v WHERE  ORDER BY v.versionMajor DESC, v.versionMinor DESC, v.versionPatch DESC, v.createdAt DESC
```

As you can see, nothing between `WHERE` and `ORDER`.

The query builder code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Get the criteria array for versions
 * @param SoftwareProduct $product Required. The product to check versions for
 * @param SoftwareOperatingSystem $operatingSystem Required. The operating system you are using.
 * @param string $version Optional. Approximate or exact version to check for. Eg 2.0 Might return 2.0.2
 * @param string $order Should be ASC or DESC. Default: DESC
 * @param int|null $limit How many results you want. Leave blank for all
 * @return SoftwareVersion[]
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getVersions(
    SoftwareProduct $product,
    SoftwareOperatingSystem $operatingSystem = null,
    $version = null,
    $order = 'DESC',
    $limit = null
) {

    if ($order != 'DESC' && $order != 'ASC') {
        throw new \DomainException("Invalid order '$order'");
    }

    $builder = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQueryBuilder();

    $builder
        ->select('v')
        ->from('\Database\Entity\SoftwareVersion', 'v')
        ->andWhere('v.deletedAt IS NULL')
        ->andWhere($builder->expr()->lt('v.releaseDate', ':releaseDate'))
        ->setParameter('releaseDate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->andWhere($builder->expr()->eq('v.product', ':product'))
        ->setParameter('product', $product->getId())
        ;

    // Anonymous function for simplified code
    $equalIfExists = function ($key, $value) use ($builder) {
        if ($value !== null) {
            $builder
                ->andWhere($builder->expr()->eq("v.$key", ":$key"))
                ->setParameter($key, $value);
        }
    };

    // OS
    $equalIfExists('operatingSystem', $operatingSystem);

    // Version Number
    $versionObject = $this->stringToVersion($version);
    $equalIfExists('versionMajor', $versionObject->getVersionMajor());
    $equalIfExists('versionMinor', $versionObject->getVersionMinor());
    $equalIfExists('versionPatch', $versionObject->getVersionPatch());

    // Version Meta
    $builder
        ->andWhere($builder->expr()->like("v.meta", ":meta"))
        ->setParameter('meta', $versionObject->getMeta() ? "{$versionObject->getMeta()}%" : '');

    $builder
        ->addOrderBy('v.versionMajor', $order)
        ->addOrderBy('v.versionMinor', $order)
        ->addOrderBy('v.versionPatch', $order)
        ->addOrderBy('v.createdAt', $order);

    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    if ($limit) {
        $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    return $query->execute();
}
```

I know, it looks pretty complicated, but even if we take the first few lines:

```
$builder
    ->select('v')
    ->from('\Mischief\Database\Entity\SoftwareVersion', 'v')
    ->andWhere('v.deletedAt IS NULL')
```

It still doesn't work.

What's more interesting: this code is live and functions as expected. I've checked the project dependencies are the same.

The docker file for my PHP container is this:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
```

I can't see any modules on live that aren't in here.

So where is my `WHERE`? :)

Please ask if I can offer any more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder
    ->select('v')
    ->from('\Database\Entity\SoftwareVersion', 'v')
    ->where('v.deletedAt IS NULL')
    ->andwhere($builder->expr()->lt('v.releaseDate', ':releaseDate'))
    ->andwhere($builder->expr()->eq('v.product', ':product'))
    ->setParameter('releaseDate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->setParameter('product', $product->getId())
    ;
```

Comment: I've tried this too. The first `->where()` works, but then `->andWhere()` produces an exception (once I've got my container back up I'll let you know the exception). As I mentioned though, using `->andWhere()` works fine in live.

Comment: Apologies, not an exception, I get this instead:
`29-Apr-2016 12:58:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 13 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 24.684632 seconds from start`